# GROUP BY and SELECT in a SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

My problem is solved but now i have a few performance questions.

I want an overview of my caught pokemon for all editions, it works as far as i tried, but i don't think it's best practice.

```
select 
  #p.idpokemons as ID,
  #p.name as Pokemon,
  #t.name as Trainer,
  tpe.idpokemons as ID,
  (select name from pokemons p where p.idpokemons = tpe.idpokemons) as Pokemon,
  (select name from trainer t where t.idtrainer = tpe.idtrainer) as Trainer,
  max(case when ideditions = 'x' then status end) as statusX, 
  max(case when ideditions = 'y' then status end) as statusY, 
  max(case when ideditions = 'or' then status end) as statusOR, 
  max(case when ideditions = 'as' then status end) as statusAS, 
  max(case when ideditions = 'sun' then status end) as statusSun, 
  max(case when ideditions = 'moon' then status end) as statusMoon 
from trainer_pokemon_edition tpe
#JOIN pokemons p ON p.idpokemons = tpe.idpokemons
#JOIN trainer t ON t.idtrainer = tpe.idtrainer
group by tpe.idpokemons;
```

**Edit:**
Just changed the Query to something like Thorstens answer, because its faster then my old one.
I commented the joins out, because in my application im getting 721 rows returned and with joins the query is slower than with subquery `0,021s/0,00034s` JOINs against `0,0030s/0,013s` Subquery Duration/Fetch.
Why is it like this, the fetchtime on Joins is faster, but the duration not?

[image of db design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBB1k.png)

And here is a link to [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7d29/13), with testdata.

Comment: The question *"Is this something you would do?"* only has meaning in a certain context. You gave no context. What are you trying to achieve? (Also, use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to give a working example of the relevant tables. That's 100 times better than a screenshot.)

Comment: Thanks for cleaning my post, Tomalak, added 'context' and a sqlfiddle link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show all your pokemons and their statuses? But their are many trainer_pokemon_edition records per pokemon, so there can be different statuses per x, per y etc. You'll have to decide which one to show; the maximum? a concatenated string showing all statuses? something else? It's also strange that there is a table holding the editions, but your query deals with certain ones and shows them in columns.

However, to get the status per pokemon simply aggregate your data:

```
select 
  (select name from pokemons p where p.idpokemons = tpe.idpokemons) as pokemon,
  max(case when ideditions = 'x' then status end) as statusx, 
  max(case when ideditions = 'y' then status end) as statusy, 
  max(case when ideditions = 'or' then status end) as statusor, 
  max(case when ideditions = 'as' then status end) as statusas, 
  max(case when ideditions = 'sun' then status end) as statussun, 
  max(case when ideditions = 'moon' then status end) as statusmoon, 
  max(case when ideditions = 'b' then status end) as statusb, 
  max(case when ideditions = 'r' then status end) as statusr 
from trainer_pokemon_edition tpe
group by idpokemons;
```

Of course you can also join with the pokemons table instead of getting the name in a subquery in the select clause.

Comment: Just tried your query, with added Subquery `(select name from trainer t where t.idtrainer = tpe.idtrainer) as Trainer,`

Comment: Don't do that. You group by `idpokemons`. There can be many trainers for one pokemon. `tpe.idtrainer` gets you one of them arbitrarily chosen. That is probably not what you are after. So: what trainer do you actually want to show per pokemon? Or do you want to show a list of pokemon / trainer pairs instead of a list of pokemons maybe? In that case `group by idpokemons, idtrainer`.

Comment: Only wantted to show pokemons per trainer, with `WHERE tpe.idtrainer = 1`. But something like
     Pokemon | Trainer | Status
     Bisasam  |    Foo   | Seen
                     |   Bar     | Caught
Looks interesting too..

Comment: Okay, when there is only one trainer you look at, then no problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
Else you have to do something like this for each edition.

```
SELECT 
  p.name AS Pokemon,
  t.name AS Trainer,
   case when max(redCaught.idpokemons) is not null then 'Caught' else 'No' end as 'Red',
   case when max(blueCaught.idpokemons) is not null then 'Caught' else 'No' end as 'Blue'
FROM
  trainer_pokemon_edition tpe
  left join (select distinct idpokemons,idtrainer from trainer_pokemon_edition tpe where status = "Caught" and ideditions='r') redCaught 
  on redCaught.idpokemons = tpe.idpokemons and tpe.ideditions='r' and redCaught.idtrainer = tpe.idtrainer
   left join (select distinct idtrainer,idpokemons from trainer_pokemon_edition tpe where status = "Caught" and ideditions='b') blueCaught 
  on blueCaught.idpokemons = tpe.idpokemons and tpe.ideditions='b' and blueCaught.idtrainer = tpe.idtrainer
   inner JOIN pokemons p ON p.idpokemons = tpe.idpokemons
   inner JOIN trainer t ON t.idtrainer = tpe.idtrainer
  group by tpe.idpokemons,tpe.idtrainer;
```

Wouldn't it be easier to do something like this?

```
SELECT distinct
  p.idpokemons AS ID,
  p.name AS Pokemon,
  t.name AS Trainer,
  e.name,
  tpe.status
FROM
  trainer_pokemon_edition tpe
  JOIN pokemons p ON p.idpokemons = tpe.idpokemons
  JOIN trainer t ON t.idtrainer = tpe.idtrainer
  join editions e on e.ideditions = tpe.ideditions
 where status = "Caught"
GROUP BY
  Pokemon,tpe.idtrainer,status
```

Comment: It looks easer.. and is faster too.
But i need columns for each edition, is it possible?

Comment: See the update, issue is that for every edition, you need to add a join and a case.